# Ascent e (é) in tab panel titles in Shiny R

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, tabpanel

I am trying to assign a title to a tabpanel as "Démarrer" in a shiny application. But it appears as "DÃ©marrer" in the shiny app.

tabPanle(titele = "Démarrer")

Does anyone know how to get it properly in the app as "Démarrer"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your code file is not in UTF-8. You can try to switch to it using File/Save with encoding).

By the way as a general rule of thumb you can set it as your permanent default encoding by checking the corresponding box in the save with encoding dialog)

Otherwise you might try to use HTML entities to code your accents (remove the space between & and eacute;).

> tabPanel(title=HTML("D& eacute;marrer"))

Comment: I have saved it as UTF-8. But it did not work out. I tried your suggestion as well both with and without space between & and eacute. But it does not work.

Comment: Sorry you have to enclose it with an HTML function

Comment: Maybe close/reopen file after saving with encoding ? You must also ensure that your accents are correct after changing encoding.

Comment: I do not know much about HTML.

Comment: It is very strange, Because in the same app, I have navbarPage and all tabs inside navbarPage reads é correctly, But outside tabPanel titles do not read it

Comment: See updated code above. Otherwise I've just tried with an UTF-8 file and a tabPanel("Démarrer") and it show perfectly in RStudio viewer and external viewer (Firefox) on Windows but with UTF-8 it should be the same with other platforms.
I think also that tabPanel is not meant to be used outside of a navBarPage or a tabsetPanel that may change it's behaviour.

Comment: thanks it works. I found another way also. try this tabPanel("\U00E9")